# jQuery: What is the problem with this jQuery.css() call?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

IE doesn't like the sharp symbol in the line below

```
jQuery(this).css('background-color','#' + jQuery(this).prev().val());
```

so I'm wondering if there is a different way to write the same without get error in IE?

Comment: What error do you get? I've used code similar to that (that is, concatenate '#' + variable to get something), and it works perfectly in IE. Might the error just be that $(this).prev().val() is null or empty?

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Yeah, looks like IE doesn't like the empty value.

Added a check and it works fine now.

Thanks!

Comment: The error was "Invalid property value" and yes it was working fine in other browsers, at least in firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested `$(this).css('background-color', '#fff000');` in IE and it works fine so I don't think it's the sharp. It's how the color is either being constructed or an issue with quotes. Try:

```
var newColorTest1 = '#' + jQuery(this).prev().val();
alert(newColorTest1);
jQuery(this).css('background-color', newColorTest1);
```

What is shown in the alert box?

What is the value of `jQuery(this).prev().val();` in your markup?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was that the value was empty in some cases and that caused the error.

if(jQuery(this).prev().val() != '')

solved it.

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking as the answer if investigating `jQuery(this).prev().val();` assisted in finding the root cause...